# how to set client_max_body_size dynamic for nginx

Tags: dynamic, nginx, patch

I want to config dynamically client_max_body_size using a variable in nginx config.

```
set $max_body 100M; 
client_max_body_size $max_body;
```

How to patch nginx for this?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you realize what you are asking?

Comment: Hi @XavierLucas, I want to set up "client_max_body_size" dynamically by a variable(not an absolute value in directive) look like above. But I don't know how to edit nginx core to do that.

Answer (score 5):

You can't.

Directive `client_max_body_size` doesn't accept variables and is not usable in a `if` block.